# Bring back a single person using id in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui.router. I need to pass an id through to the controller to display one person on a detail page. I have been able to get the id through to the controller but am not sure how to continue..

I want to do something like SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE personID = $stateParams.personID // sorry for using a SQL/Angular mashup but I think you would get what I mean.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<a ui-sref="person({personID:{{people.people}}})" href="">
```

And the controller..

```
myApp.controller('peopleCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function( $scope, $stateParams )
{

    // This outputs the id as expected for instance 1
    console.log($stateParams.personID);



    $scope.people =
    [
        {
            "personID":1,
            "firstName": "A",
            "lastName": "Grem"
        },
        {
            "personID":2,
            "firstName": "B",
            "lastName": "Grem"
        },
        {
            "personID":3,
            "firstName": "C",
            "lastName": "Grem"
        },
        {
            "personID":4,
            "firstName": "D",
            "lastName": "Grem"
        },
    ];
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect time to learn about resolves.

Resolves functions which execute before your state is loaded. Resolves can return a promise, such as a $http call.  The result of the promise can be injected into your controller, using the resolve's name.

The resolve can also be injected.  Here, I inject $stateParams to get your personID parameter.  Using the param, I fetch the person data from a REST api.  Finally, when the http call returns, I return the unwrapped response's data, which is what is provided when "resolvedPerson" is injected in the controller.

```
$stateProvider.state('person', {
    url: '/person/:personID',
    resolve: { 
      resolvedPerson: function($stateParams) { 
        $http.get("/restapi/person/" + $stateParams.personID)
          .then(function(response) { return response.data; });
      }
    },
    templateUrl: 'person.html',
    controller: 'peopleCtrl'
});

myApp.controller('peopleCtrl', ['$scope', 'resolvedPerson', function( $scope, resolvedPerson ) {
  $scope.person = resolvedPerson;
}
```

link:

```
<a ui-sref="person({ personID: people.person.personID })"> {{ people.person.name }}</a>
```

person.html

```
<pre>{{person}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
href="personStateUrl/{{people.people}}"
```

Because in your config you have normally declared an url for state('person') it should look like this

```
   .state('person', {
        url: '/person/:personID',
        ...
    });
```

And after get your id thanks to

```
  var personID = $stateParams.personID;
```

Comment: Should note that this of course only gives the person id, so in order to achieve the select * from op a new api/db request is necessary. This is mostly not a problem though as you usually fetch a small resultset to show the item list while you fetch a expanded result when you want to show all details for a spesific item.

Comment: @JimL am I correct in thinking that I pass the id to server side that will pass back what I need?

Comment: See angular $http to request your server.